# Modular forms on $\Gamma_0(N)$ with character in Sage

Tags: modular-forms, sagemath

I'm trying to work with modular forms on $\Gamma_0(N)$ with character in Sage.

In particular, I've been using the following:

```
sage.modular.modform.constructor.CuspForms(group, weight)
sage.modular.modform.constructor.EisensteinForms(group, weight)
sage.modular.modform.constructor.ModularForms(group, weight)
```

The `group` parameter can be either a congruence subgroup, like `Gamma0(N)` or `Gamma1(N)`, or a Dirichlet character, like `DirichletGroup(5)[0]`.

**The problem:** if you set `group` to a Dirichlet character $\chi$ of conductor $C$, then the above functions return spaces of modular forms on $(\Gamma_1(C), \chi)$, aka, forms on $\Gamma_1(C)$.

Using these functions or others, is there a way to get the spaces of modular forms on $(\Gamma_0(C), \chi)$ ?

Comment: If you carefully and rigorously define what you mean by each of the two spaces you mention above, you'll find that they are equal.   I.e., your question is a non-question once you understand spaces of modular forms better.

Comment: Let $\chi$ be a Dirichlet character of conductor $N$. Are you saying that $M_k(\Gamma_0(N), \chi) = M_k(\Gamma_1(N), \chi) = M_k(\Gamma_1(N))$?

I'm aware that $M_k(\Gamma_1(N)) = \displaystyle\oplus_{\chi} M_k(\Gamma_0(N), \chi)$, where the sum runs over all characters of conductor $N$. 

However, I'm looking to examine $M_k(\Gamma_0(N), \chi)$ for a _particular_ character $\chi$.

Comment: This is entirely a question of notation. What Sage calls $M_k(\Gamma_1(N), \chi)$ is what you are calling $M_k(\Gamma_0(N), \chi)$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Why the discrepancy?

Comment: Matter of taste: you can either think of this space as a space of functions invariant under the weight $k$ action of $\Gamma_1(N)$, and with the diamond operators acting via the character $\chi$; or as the space of functions invariant under $\Gamma_0(N)$ for a "$\chi$-twisted" weight $k$ action $f \mapsto \chi(d)^{-1} (cz + d)^{-k} f((az + b) / (cz + d))$, which restricts to the usual weight $k$ action on $\Gamma_1(N)$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks again for taking the time to explain. If you think the question is worth having an answer, feel free to submit an answer and I'll accept it.